# Unable to load as datatime for dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am loading with MySQL Workbench > Table Date Import and Selecting my Excel CSV file to load (CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited))

```
Date        A       B   C
10/31/2017  1000000 1.7 1234.4
9/30/2017   2000000 3.5 1485.5
8/31/2017   3000000 5.4 1336.5
```

I am able to load this when I select the Field Type as text but not datettime.

When I select FieldType as date time it loads only the header without the data.

Can anyone please advise?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to provide the format of the datetime ?

Comment: its was originally in excel as date format for the date column.. in the screenshot I also tested selecting the Field Type as Datetime but it upload only the header without data (selecting as text will upload the data properly but in text format)